# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Crashes when I click new schema comparison

Tags: visual-studio-2010, schema-compare

As the title says, I am using a full version of VS2010 Ultimate and everytime I try to do a schema comparison VS crashes.

The debug error is: Unhandled exception at 0x75549617 in devenv.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352.

Anyone had this issue and can you help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue, The Productivity Power Tools Extension was causing the problem.

I started going through disabling all the extenstions one at a time, and I found this to be the culprit.

I will leave this here for anyone else how comes across this issue.

Comment: More specifically, it's the "Solution Navigator" part of this, which at least you can turn off in Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools. Not sure why, but I can leave everything else on and all's well.

Comment: Did either of you let the folks who build the Productivity Power Tools know about this?

Comment: I didn't no. I didn't think about it, and this is over a year old now :)